# iOS in-app sign up or subscribing by phone

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to have a phone number displayed, and tappable on my app in which the user could call to subscribe to my service.

I'm aware that the App Store guidelines mention going to an external browser, but it doesn't mention anything about "phone-in" subscriptions.

Does anyone know if what I'm proposing is allowed?

Comment: You would have to check with Apple to be certain, but the answer seems obvious. The reason you cannot have in-app payments through non-Apple servers is Apple wants to make their 30%. If you have a way for them not to, they're not likely to roll out the red carpet for you to do so.

Comment: What Apple will or won't allow really isn't on topic for Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [*What kind of questions can I ask here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Ok.. so where's the appropriate place to put this topic?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience Apple isn't very flexible in their guidelines. They make the final decision, and loopholes aren't something they're going to be lenient on.  I would lean towards them disallowing what you're attempting.  I wouldn't make that a core component of your app.